# Можно ли сделать запрет для бота, писать только в отдельном канале? discord.py

Tags: discord, бот, discord.py

Я делаю бота для дискорд с помощью discord.py, и хочу сделать ему запрет отвечать на команды во всех каналах кроме тех которые я укажу. У меня есть небольшой код, но его приходиться писать в каждой команде, а ето не удобно.

Можно ли сделать такой запрет, или может можно сделать мой код сразу для всех команд?

Вот мой код:

```
channell = ctx.message.channel
channel1 = client.get_channel(929090952763703316)
if channell != channel1:
    await ctx.send("Тут нельзя!")
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
else:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать как декоратор:

```
def predicate(ctx: commands.Context):
    channel = nextcord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, id='айди текстового канала')
    if ctx.channel != channel:
        return False
    else:
        return True

has_channel = commands.check(predicate)

@commands.command()
@has_channel
async def test(self, ctx):
    pass
```

Можете ещё добавить обработчик ошибок